# aws serverless multiple yaml java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I got AWS sample serverless app in which I have single yaml files along with multiples handlers.

The problem is that template.yaml is keep growing, how can separate yaml for each handler or group of handlers so it would be easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

For our projects we started dividing the main YAML into multiple on in a next way:

- all lambdas are still described in serverless.yml file
- in serverless.yml

  ```
  resources:
   - ${file(./sls-config/cognito-user-pools-authorizer.yml)}
   - ${file(./sls-config/aurora.yml)}
   - ${file(./sls-config/bucket.yml)}
   - ${file(./sls-config/queues.yml)}
   - ${file(./sls-config/alarms.yml)}
   - ${file(./sls-config/roles.yml)}
   - ${file(./sls-config/outputs.yml)}
  ```

Yep, splitting of the resources up to you.

- alarm.yml

  ```
  Resources:
     SQSAlarmTopic:
         Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
         Properties:
               DisplayName: ${self:provider.prefix}-sqs-alarm-topic
               TopicName: ${self:provider.prefix}-sqs-alarm-topic
               Subscription:
                 - Endpoint: example-email@mail.com
                   Protocol: email
               Tags: ${self:custom.sqsTags}
  ```

  and so on.
- outputs.yml

  ```
  Outputs:
      CognitoUserPoolId:
          Value: ${self:custom.userPool}
      CognitoUserPoolClientId:
          Value: ${self:custom.userPoolClientId}
      DSClusterID:
          Description: "RDS Cluster "
          Value: { Ref: RDSCluster }
      DBAddress:
          Value: !GetAtt RDSCluster.Endpoint.Address
  ```

The variables from custom and provide may be used easily through the sub_configs.yml.

Be careful with spacing/paddings in yaml files :)